Group by values in column, creating new colum where duplicates occur in first column
My dataset is similar to this
  User     Email

0 Ed       ed@gmail.com
1 Heidi    heidi@gmail.com
2 Ed       ed@hotmail.com
3 Nick     nick@gmail.com 
4 Nick     nick@gmail.com
5 Duncan   duncan@hotmail.com
6 Lucy     lucy@hotmail.com
7 Duncan   duncan@gmail.com
8 Ed       ed@myspace.com

I would like to groupby the values in the User column, but where there are duplicate entries with different values in the Email column, create a new column. So my new dataset will look like:
  User    Email                Email_2            Email_3

0 Ed      ed@gmail.com         ed@hotmail.com     ed@myspace.com
1 Heidi   heidi@gmail.com
2 Nick    nick@gmail.com
3 Duncan  duncan@hotmail.com   duncan@gmail.com
4 Lucy    lucy@hotmail.com

The titles of the new columns are not important, I just want one name in the User column and a column for each email address that exists for that User.

de-duplicate the User with groupby.cumcount, then pivot using the de-duplicated series as column

Hi, thank you for this answer, however I am having difficulty identifying what I need to do based on your advice - would you please be able to expand on this a little?

Please read the Question #10 in the duplicate link, and the matching answer here
